# Does anyone know how to use schematic in MODELSIM?

Tags: modelsim

I am unable to use add to schematic in modelsim se64 10.5. Getting this error :

> Could not open the database because the required debug information has not been generated.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run vsim with the `-debugdb` flag, this will create the vsim.dbg file which contains schematic connectivity info (amongst others).

The User Manual contains all the info you need, just search for debugdb.